# Python Conditional Key/Value in Dict

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following piece of code:

```
payload = [
    {
        'car': {
            'vin': message.car_reference.vin,
            'brand': message.car_reference.model_manufacturer,
            'model': message.car_reference.model_description,
            'color': message.car_reference.color,
        },
    }
]
```

The only field on message.car_reference that is guaranteed to not be None is vin.
I still want the other keys (brand, model, color) to be in the dict only if they have a value.

The payload gets send to an external API that gives me an error if e.g. color = None.

How do I make it so that keys and values are only added, if their value is not None?

What came to my mind until now was mutlitple if-statements, but that looks awful and I don't think it's the right way.

Comment: i may be onto something already. What if I add all the keys and assign their values and later iterate over the dict and check for keys with empty values?

Comment: Just to clarify, is there a reason that the payload consists of a dict inside a list? Are you intending to send multiple dicts?

Comment: @jrmylow as I said in the question description the payload gets send to an external API, this is the format they want me to send it. The dict around the car dict is like an order, there can be multiple orders in one list. I also removed a few of the keys and values from the example since it could contain customer data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code recursively looks inside the data structure

```py
def recur_remover(collection):
    if isinstance(collection, list):
        # This allows you to pass in the whole list immediately
        for item in collection:
            recur_remover(item)
    
    elif isinstance(collection, dict):
        # When you hit a dictionary, this checks if there are nested dictionaries    
        to_delete = []
        for key, val in collection.items():
            if val is None:
                to_delete.append(key)
            else:
                recur_remover(collection[key])
        for k in to_delete:
            # deletes all unwanted keys at once instead of mutating the dict each time
            del collection[k]
    else:
        return
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! I had to correct 2 mistakes, can I edit your answer? 2 colons are missing, one in the def and one in the 2nd for loop

Comment: Edited to add an explanation and add the colons

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you may do this

```
your_car_collection = [{'car': {k: v for k, v in car['car'].items() if v}} for car in your_car_collection]
```